RegionBoundary of a cylinder
Bug persist from version 11.3 to version 14.1.
I generated 300 points  (shown in Red) inside an oriented cylinder and I wanted these points to map onto the nearest locations (shown in Green) on the RegionBoundary of the cylinder . I thought that the wall of the cylinder as well as the top/bottom plate would constitute the boundary.
cyl = Cylinder[{{0, 3, -1}, {0, 0, 1}}, 3]
pts = RandomPoint[cyl, 300];
ptsToBoundary = RegionNearest[RegionBoundary@cyl, #] & /@ pts;
lines = MapThread[Line@{##} &, {pts, ptsToBoundary}];

Graphics3D[{Red, Point@pts
  , Darker@Green, Point@ptsToBoundary
  (*, Black, Thin, lines*) (*uncomment to see lines *)
  , Transparent, cyl
  }
 , BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}
 ]




1- What constitutes the RegionBoundary of the cylinder?
2- What is the pronounced Green line in the middle of the cylinder toward which the outputs of the RegionNearest are directed? You can uncomment the line in the code to see those.
I am using v12.2.0 but the behavior is the same on the cloud.

RegionBoundary  seems does not work. We have to use RegionBoundary@BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics@cyl

Thanks @cvgmt. Are there guidelines on where the RegionBoundary chould be used on it own?

@cvgmt:  RegionBoundary does work for a cylinder: Area[RegionBoundary@Cylinder[{{0, 3, -1}, {0, 0, 1}}, 3]] results in 6 (3 \[Pi] + Sqrt[13] \[Pi]) and Volume[RegionBoundary@Cylinder[{{0, 3, -1}, {0, 0, 1}}, 3]] produces Undefined.

As I understand it, there is a problem with RandomPoint in 14.1 on Windows, Look at the result of pts = RandomPoint[Cylinder[{{0, 3, -1}, {0, 0, 1}}, 3], 3000];ListPointPlot3D[pts].

cyl = Cylinder[{{0, 3, -1}, {0, 0, 1}}, 3]; pts = RandomPoint[cyl, 3000]; {ListPointPlot3D[pts, PlotStyle -> Red, BoxRatios -> Automatic,     SphericalRegion -> True],   Graphics3D[{Transparent, Cylinder[{{0, 3, -1}, {0, 0, 1}}, 3]}    , BoxRatios -> Automatic, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05]    ]   } // Show . I can't see any anomalies. To what are you referring? @user64494

@Syed: I see an oblique cylinder, not a right cylinder. The same issue in Wolfram Cloud.

I see this on the cloud.

@Syed: Did you try to rotate the plot and  see it from different points?

@user64494 Try ListPointPlot3D[pts, BoxRatios -> Automatic].

@A.Kato: Thank you. I got it.

I have test 11.3,12.2,12.3,13.3.1,14.0,14.1 ,none of them can get the RegionBoundary  of the  Cylinder.

@cvgmt, please add a bugs header in this case when it is convenient for you. Thanks for the investigation.

Clear["Global`*"];
cyl = Cylinder[{{0, 3, -1}, {0, 0, 1}}, 3];
pts = RandomPoint[cyl, 300];


We can use CylindricalDecomposition with "Boundary" to get the expression of the boundary of Cylinder, but it is too slow to calculate the nearest points to such boundary. compare to the BoundaryDiscreteRegion method.

expr = CylindricalDecomposition[
    RegionMember[cyl, {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}, "Boundary"] // Simplify;
boundary = ImplicitRegion[expr, {x, y, z}];
(*  boundary//Area//FullSimplify  *) 
nearest1 = RegionNearest[boundary];
nearest2 = RegionNearest[RegionBoundary@BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[cyl]];
nearest1 /@ pts[[1 ;; 2]]
nearest2 /@ pts[[1 ;; 2]]


Since nearest1 too slow, we have to use nearest2.

Graphics3D[{Red, Point@pts, Darker@Green, Point[nearest2 /@ pts], 
  Transparent, cyl}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, Boxed -> False]



I have tried several examples with cuboids and spheres where RegionBoundary works as it should. This seems to a bug but whether it originates in RegionBoundary or due to the Cylinder, I can't say for sure. Can you please add the bugs tag and header of the post as you see fit.

@Syed Thanks, I will test this example in the old version ( in another computer)tomorrow , after that we would add bugs tags.
